# PyGame independent background image

Tags: animation, background, pygame, sprite

I am having a problem that I wish you guys could help me.
In this soccer game when i move the player around the field the goals dont stick to there positions and they move along with the ball.

Example:

[image]

```
import pygame
import random
import sys, glob
from pygame.locals import *



class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,x,y,image_x):
        self.bottom = 20
        self.image = pygame.image.load("res/images/ball1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        screen.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y))
        self.change_x=x
        self.change_y=y





class Field(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #self.field = pygame.image.load('res/images/field.png').convert()
        #self.field_rect = self.field.get_rect()
        #self.field_rect.x = 0  
        #screen.blit(self.field,(self.field_rect.x,self.field_rect.y))


    def goal_top(self):      
        self.goal_top = pygame.image.load("res/images/goal-top.png")
        screen.blit(self.goal_top,(425,0))

    def goal_bottom(self): 

        self.goal_bottom = pygame.image.load("res/images/goal-btm.png")
        self.goal_bottom_rect = self.goal_bottom.get_rect()
        self.goal_bottom_rect.y = 720

        screen.blit(self.goal_bottom,(425,self.goal_bottom_rect.y ))        




class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,x,y,image_x,image_y):
        self.bottom = 20
        self.image = pygame.image.load("res/images/player/boy.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        screen.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y))
        self.change_x=x
        self.change_y=y



    def changespeed_x(self,x):
        self.change_x = x

    def changespeed_y(self,y):
        self.change_y = y  




class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func

        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)


    def apply(self, target):

        try:
            return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)
        except AttributeError:
            return map(sum, zip(target, self.state.topleft))


    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)


def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l + HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling left
    l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling right
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return Rect(l, t, w, h)




pygame.init() 

# Set the height and width of the screen 
WIN_WIDTH = 963
WIN_HEIGHT = 760
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

size=[WIN_WIDTH,WIN_HEIGHT] 
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
#screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size,FULLSCREEN)

pygame.display.set_caption("Soccer") 
clock=pygame.time.Clock() 


x=500
y=280


set_ball_x = 500
set_ball_y = 300
shot = False
type=''
dir_y=0



##INITIAL POSITION OF IMAGES
image_x=0
image_y=0
ball_image_x=0


dir_y=0

   ##CAMERA TRACK
total_level_width = 963 ##BACKGROUND (Field) width
total_level_height = 1200 ##BACKGROUND (Field) height
camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
background = pygame.image.load('res/images/field.png').convert()
background_rect = background.get_rect()




while 1:


    clock.tick(20)

    screen.blit(background, camera.apply((0,0)))

    ball = Ball(set_ball_x,set_ball_y,ball_image_x)


    camera.update(ball)

    player = Player(x,y,image_x,image_y)


    field = Field()
    field.goal_top()
    field.goal_bottom()



    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x=x+6
        pos =+1
        image_x = 0

        if image_y < 90:
            image_y +=30
        else:
            image_y = 0



    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x=x-6
        image_x = 130 

        if image_y < 90:
            image_y +=30
        else:
            image_y = 0



    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]:
        y=y-6

        image_x = 195


        if image_y < 90:
            image_y +=30
        else:
            image_y = 0
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y=y+6 


        image_x = 70


        if image_y < 90:
            image_y +=30
        else:
            image_y = 0    


    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player,ball):
        set_ball_x = player.change_x
        set_ball_y = player.change_y+20

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.QUIT]:
            sys.exit()

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_q]: ## KEY "Q" to EXIT
            sys.exit()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()  
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.flip()       
    pygame.display.update()
```

Any ideas why this is happening?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What is `Camera.apply()` doing?

This:

```
l, t, _, _ = target_rect
_, _, w, h = camera
```

Should be:

```
loc = target_rect.topleft
size = camera.size
```

And

```
l, t, _, _ = -l + HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h
```

If you're trying to get the center coordinate? You use

```
loc = target_rect.center
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the reply. The Camera.apply() is what makes the "update" screen with the coordinates to move the background up,and down. I got no luck with code you gave me... The problem is that the goal_bottom.y should be something like -1100 but if i put a value that is not the size of the screen it never shows.

Comment: To have objects scroll, you use 'world coordinates', which you convert to 'screen coordinates' to blit. What it means is you store a topleft coordinate, and modify that to scroll. Here's an example using tilesets. But its  simpler than it sounds. http://code.google.com/p/ninmonkey/source/browse/examples/maptiles_numpy/map.py

Comment: Thank you monkey, but i think the problem is in the class camera i will try a different approach in the way the field moves, maybe work with the rect.y to move objects in the field.